# Rails(utf-8 encoding issue): Active record fetching msyqldb data incorrectly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, utf-8, character-encoding

one of my Model's attribute(name) has this data

```
name = "Cirque du SoleilÂ® at Mandalay"
result = Model.find_by_name()
puts result
"Cirque du Soleil\xC3\x82\xC2\xAE at Mandalay"
```

when rails fetching the data, why it is not fetching correctly?

And when I am trying to store this data into oracle db.
I am getting this error.

```
ERROR -- : Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII: INSERT INTO "ACTIVITIES"."ACTIVITY_COLLECTIONS" ("ID", "NAME", "CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT", "IS_CUSTOM", "PRODUCT_ID", "URL_SLUG") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7)
```

my database.yml has

```
encoding: utf8
```

I added in boot.rb

```
ENV['NLS_LANG'] = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8'
```

Please help me out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

It was happening because of the mysql gem version.

Updated it to

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

Previously I was using

```
gem 'mysql'
```